# Primefaces validateContentType is not working

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, primefaces-fileupload

I am using **primefaces 8.0.2** fileupload with the following :

**javax.faces 2.4.0**

**tomcat 9.0.46 (standalone windows service)**

**java 8**

**tika-core 1.24.1**

```
<p:fileUpload id="imageFileUpload" style="margin-right:40px;" styleClass="customFileUpload" 
                            listener="#{requestBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"                                 
                                   sequential="true"
                                   multiple="true"
                                   process="@this"
                                   onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();"
                                   oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide();"
                                   allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png|tiff|pdf|doc?x|xls?x)$/i"
                                   accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.tiff,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx"
                                   validateContentType="true"
                                   invalidFileMessage="Invalid file type"
                                   sizeLimit="10485760"                            
                                   invalidSizeMessage="Maximum file size is 10 MB"
                                   update="uploadMessages attachmentsTable" auto="true" label="Choose file"  />
```

I am using the following dependency for apache tika :

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

the fileupload works only for images and pdf but when trying to choose xls | xslx | doc | docx
no error message appears and no file was uploaded
while when choosing invalid file (.exe) for example, i get a validation error message
so i am wondering why the excel and word are not getting uploaded ?

Comment: Don't you need `docx?|xlsx?` instead of `doc?x|xls?x` in the `allowTypes` attribute?

Comment: the syntax above is correct, even if you tried the straightforward one it also doesn't work : doc|docx|xls|xlsx

Comment: Doesn't Tika also require POI for determining XLSX, DOC etc?  PDF it uses Magic bytes so it doesn't need another library.

Comment: i also have poi in my classpath

Comment: BTW. Are you sure that you're using JSF 2.4? Have you read this:https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2018/04/do-not-use-orgglassfish-mojarra-240.html?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dependency `tika-core` I had to use `tika-java7` dependency in maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-java7</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It seems like this package contains the necessary `FileTypeDetector` implementations.

It works for me (Java 11, JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces 12).